Cannot invoke "org.gradle.util.Path.segmentCount()" because "path" is null
facing this error while running tests in intellij with BDD framework
Cannot invoke "org.gradle.util.Path.segmentCount()" because "path" is null
using java 21 & gradle version 8.5

What's the full stack trace? What is the contents of your build file?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have experienced very similar problem (with the same error message). Gradle task was executing smoothly from command line, but not from IntelliJ Idea. I just removed "Run as test" from Gradle configuration
Gradle configuration
